# Login into the application using Jmeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter

I have been trying to login into the application using the JMeter tool. Though I have provided all the parameters in the request but the scenario was unable to get replicate at my end.

I have used HTTP Request sampler.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you want help you need to provide way more details (test plan screenshot, failing request zoom, application authentication scheme...)

Comment: Hi can you replicate the scenario which I have mentioned prviously for this portal   http://sofolympiadtrainer.com/rw-user/login.jsp    credentials are : username: nigamharsh28@gmail.com password : Ciquser1  It is a test user.

Comment: I have used following in the parameter request along with the http sampler :  j_password-> Ciquser1  -> false    -> true
j_username-> nigamharsh28@gmail.com -> false -> true
rembembermePasswordId -> 1 -> false  -> true
remember  ->  on -> false -> true

Comment: Should I make use of HTTP Authorization Manager

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem is missing [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager). Try adding it to your test plan and see whether it resolves your issue.

If not - there may be some problems with parameters with dynamic parameters which shouldn't be hard-coded in HTTP Request. In that case you'll need to populate your test plan as follows:

1. HTTP GET Request to login page

   - extract dynamic values and convert them to JMeter variables
2. HTTP POST request to login page using JMeter variables instead of dynamic parameters.

This process is called "correlation". See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) for example of bypassing login challenge using correlation.